# how to increase the size of background image to cover all backgroung (but no repetition)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set an image as full background of a table in html  and the condition is i just have to do it using **just javascript code (no css html).**

What i have done brings the image in background but the problem is image is too small.  i want to keep this image cover the whole background by growing its size dynamically (without repetition of image at background).

My code to display the image at background is:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/mortalengines/images/b/b6/English_flag.png/revision/latest?cb=20100614220751')";
```

Now what should i add in this javascript to make this url image to cover all background by increasing size and without repetition ?

EDIT: I have seen many links they use max-width but i dont know if i can use it in given context or not. If yes then how to use it.

Comment: Your question is too broad. please try solving it yourself first and post in your question what you have tried.

Comment: I don't agree. It is completely clear what OP wants and it an answer could be short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

**[If this is what you want:](https://jsfiddle.net/rg87ota5/)**

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
table.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/mortalengines/images/b/b6/English_flag.png/revision/latest?cb=20100614220751')";
table.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
```

Comment: yes thanks.. but i dont understand why this "-5" ? the question was not that bad and was nto complicated to understand. I had tried something but couldn't achieve it.

Comment: My pleasure. Try to be more specific with the questions and provide some examples of your work.

Comment: Ok i will take care in future.

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-size:cover` CSS property.

According to the docs, the `background-size:cover` property is defined as

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the
>   background area is completely covered by the background image. Some
>   parts of the background image may not be in view within the background
>   positioning area

You can do this with **JavaScript** as follows

```
document.body.style.background-repeat="no-repeat";
document.body.style.background-size="cover";
```

Comment: Somebody is trying to downvote this answer,..why??

Comment: It is the correct answer...

Comment: im not the downvoter, but i assume you got downvoted because someone saw the word "CSS" in your answer...

Comment: @Banana But this is so irritating..we try to solve the problem of others and some others just sit and downvote...so much irritating,..

Comment: @testing Did you try this answer..please check if this is correct..

Comment: @Lal sorry it did not worked for me.